# I am trying to update an object with a new key and store it in an array. How can I do this and save the resulting array in state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I am experiencing an issue while updating an object in my ReactJS application. I am using a map statement to change the partition key of an object, but the final object still contains the original partition key. The expected behavior is for the partition key to be updated. I have included my code below, as well as the actual and desired output. Can you help me understand why the partition key is not being updated and how I can resolve this issue?

```
this.state = {
      keyb: 0,
      clockVisiblity:false,
      partitions:[
        {id:1,name:"P1"},
        {id:2,name:"P2"},
        {id:3,name:"P3"},
      ],
      dayDetails:[
       {
      "day":"Monday",
      "full_day":false,
      "partition":1,
      "start_time":"Thu Sep 01 2022 18:47:09 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
      },
      ],
      activePartition:1,

}



setPartitionsDetails=()=>{

    var partitionData = this.state.dayDetails.find((item)=>item.partition===this.state.activePartition)
    const dayDetails = this.state.partitions.map((partition) => {
      partitionData.partition=partition.id
      console.log("You object ",partitionData)
      return partitionData
      }
    )

}
```

final object of daydetails comes:

```
[
   {
      "day":"Monday",
      "full_day":false,
      "partition":3,
      "start_time":"Thu Sep 01 2022 18:47:09 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
   },
   {
      "day":"Monday",
      "full_day":false,
      "partition":3,
      "start_time":"Thu Sep 01 2022 18:47:09 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
   },
   {
      "day":"Monday",
      "full_day":false,
      "partition":3,
      "start_time":"Thu Sep 01 2022 18:47:09 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
   }
]
```

where as the desire object containers unique or different partition key.

```
[
       {
          "day":"Monday",
          "full_day":false,
          "partition":1,
          "start_time":"Thu Sep 01 2022 18:47:09 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
       },
       {
          "day":"Monday",
          "full_day":false,
          "partition":2,
          "start_time":"Thu Sep 01 2022 18:47:09 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
       },
       {
          "day":"Monday",
          "full_day":false,
          "partition":3,
          "start_time":"Thu Sep 01 2022 18:47:09 GMT+0500 (PKT)"
       }
    ]
```

Comment: can you share an expo snack for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because you're using the same instance of `partitionData` to write the value of partition, so 2 is overwritten on 1 and 3 is overwritten on 2, and you get 3 in all the instances, you can fix this by making clone of `partitionData` and return that clone after updating.

```
const dayDetails = this.state.partitions.map((partition) => {
  let partitionDataClone = {...partitionData};
  partitionDataClone.partition = partition.id
  return partitionDataClone;
})
```

As the `partition` is on the first level of this object, so the shallow cloning works here, but for nested objects, you should consider deep cloning.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your mapping the partitions so you will only have the last value, which is 3. What you could do to make sure you only use one ID is to use splice.

```js
const setPartitionsDetails = () => {
    const partitionCollection = [...this.state.partitions];

    this.state.dayDetails.forEach((_, index) => {
      var partitionData = this.state.dayDetails[index];

      if (partitionCollection.length) {
        partitionData.partition = partitionCollection.splice(0, 1)[0].id;
      }
    });
  };
```